# Сброс пароля на DomU

Tags: linux, bash, xen

Такая странная проблема имеется: не могу никак сбросить пароль на DomU домены xen.

Пробовал двумя способами.

1. Прописать single mode в pyGRUB. Single грузится, но просит ввести пароль, или я что-то не понял. Я сначала уже обрадовался думал вот оно нужно просто ввести и повторить пароль, ввел раз, говорит login incorrect.
2. Прописать init=/bin/bash в pyGRUB. Пишет:

   > /bin/bash: : No such file or directory Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Пробовал также xm shutdown машины, а затем подцепится к тому. Так ничего не получилось.

Пытаюсь отмонтировать, а он пишет, что том не примонтирован. Пытаюсь примонтировать пишет, что том уже примонтирован.

Грузился с LiveCD, так удалось сбросить пароль только на одну DomU - udom, через chroot, так как тома других DomU не удалось примонтировать. Просил ввести файловую систему при монтировании.

> mount: you must specify the filesystem type.

Так ни одна из существующих не подошла. Вообще вот список доменов:

```
Name ID Mem VCPUs State Time(s)
Domain-0 0 864 8 r----- 4557.3
services_vm 512 1 0.0
smgr 9216 1 0.9
udom 2 512 1 -b---- 1099.2
```

А вот список LVM томов этих доменов:

```
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_tmpl_env' [512,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/dom0swap' [512,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/udom' [10,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/udom1' [10,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/udomdata' [20,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/udomswap' [1,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/vsp-template' [20,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_services_vm' [3,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_services_vm_backup' [3,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_services_vm_var_sm' [1,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd0_udom' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd1_udomswap' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd2_vsp-template' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd3_udomdata' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd4_lv_services_vm' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/_drbd5_lv_services_vm_var_sm' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_sm' [30,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_smgr_sm_perf' [30,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_smgr_cs1k_apps' [10,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_emdata' [2,00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_sm_meta_' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_smgr_sm_perf_meta_' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_smgr_cs1k_apps_meta_' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/lv_emdata_meta_' [32,00 MB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/Asterisk' [48,84 GB] inherit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Загрузиться с LiveCD (на LiveCD должны быть установлены пакеты lvm2 и multipath-tools, если их нет, то нужно подключить интернет и установить их, или скачать готовые пакеты с машины имеющей доступ к интернету и установить их, например с флешки).

Aткивация lvm разделов:

```
2) vgchange -a y
```

Вывести содержимое папки mapper - там должны были появиться новые разделы после команды vgchange -a y.

```
3) cd /dev/mapper

4) ls -a
```

Посмотреть как выполнено разбиение на разделы; Создание карты устройств для блочного устройства.

```
5) kpartx -l <нужный раздел>; kpartx -a <нужный раздел>
```

Посмотреть какие новые разделы появились, один их них и есть тот, который нужен. В моем случае появилось три раздела и мне пригодился LogVol00.

```
6) ls -a
```

Примонтировать нужный раздел:

```
7) mоunt LogVol00 /mnt
```

Зайти на примонтированный раздел chroot'ом:

```
8) chroot /mnt
```

Ввести новый пароль:

```
9) passwd root
```