# Блокировка учетной записи root при попытке сброса пароля

Tags: linux, bash, centos, xen

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая проблема, при сбросе пароля на CentOS 5.6, работающей под управлением гипервизора Xen, блокируется учетка root. При чем, она блокируется при любых способах сброса. Пробовал и в shadow удалить хеш, и подцепится chroot и задать новый - passwd root. Пароль меняется, проверял в /etc/shadow, там появлялся хеш пароля, но после перезагрузки и при удалении пароля, и при его смене с Chroot войти не удавалась, опять подцеплялся с LiveCD, проверял хеш в /etc/shadow, там вместо хеша нового пароля или вместо ничего (при способе удаления) появлялось два восклицательных знака (учетка заблокирована), а между ними два апострофа,
то есть выглядело примерно так:

root:'!!': ..........

Насколько знаю, учетка заблокирована - это просто два !!, а если между ними два апострофа, это что значит?
другие способы вообще не подошли, такие как
1) xm shutdown 
xm create -c 
прописать в первой строке загрузки pyBRUB -> e -> kernell -> e -> init=/bin/bash или /bin/sh (пробовал оба) -> Enter -> b. Пишет no such file or directory, хотя в initrd она есть, точно проверено.
2) прописать single mode так же в pyGRUB. При загрузке single mode требует пароль от root:

Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):

При нажатии Control-D просто загружается как обычно и требует ввести имя пользователя и пароль.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной блокировкой? Подскажите пожалуйста?

Кстати я подумал, что может это я криворукий лопушара и блокирую его после перезагрузки сам, неправильно вводя его, и специально попробовал сбросить chroot'ом, перезагрузиться, дождаться загрузки всех виртуалок, затем не пытаясь войти в виртуалку, к которой я сбросил пароль, снова перезагрузиться с LiveCD, и посмотреть заблокировалось ли? И да, оно заблокировалось - '!!'. Что интересно, новый пароль записывается после перезагрузки в файл /etc/shadow- (shadow с черточкой), а в etc/shadow (без черточки) '!!'.

Comment: 1. это происходит в *dom0* или в *domu*? 2. каким образом был установлен *xen*?

Comment: если это происходит в *domu*, то похоже на криво написанный/исправленный стартовый скрипт. посмотрите в файлах в файловой системе *dom0*, где упоминается `/etc/shadow`. найти их можно, например, так: `find /usr/ /etc -maxdepth 3 -type d -name xen\* | xargs grep -rl /etc/shadow`

Comment: Это происходит в domu

Comment: Дело в том, что сейчас я не могу проверить у меня есть учетка только admin, обрезанная до безобразия. И , если выполняешь поиск так как вы написали то получается следующее:                        find: /usr/lib/audit: Permission denied
find: /etc/lvm/backup: Permission denied
find: /etc/lvm/cache: Permission denied
find: /etc/lvm/archive: Permission denied
find: /etc/cron.d: Permission denied

Comment: Не могу выключить сервак сейчас, на нём АТС пашет.

Comment: *у меня есть учетка только admin, обрезанная до безобразия* — для поиска того, что я предложил, это несущественно. но существенно по другой причине — если вам ограничили права на *dom0*, то что же удивительного, что вас ограничивают и на *domu*? // вы так и не ответили про то, как был установлен *xen*. устанавливал и настраивал *xen* кто-то другой?

Comment: Меня никто не ограничивал, если бы ограничивали, разве дали бы цеплятся LiveCD к разделу. Xen настраивали давно при автоматизаторе, который был за три до меня. Короче при царе горохе. Той обрезанной учеткой пользовались исключительно для захода через многочисленные web-морды которые как раз крутятся на этих виртуалках. А сейчас мне понадобился доступ root, так как я не могу через эти устаревшие web-морды поддерживающие только IE 6)) загрузить прошивки на телефон, так как закачка прошивки на сервак через web-морду постоянно срывается или зависает.

Comment: А с этой обрезанной учеткой напрямую на сервак я ничего не могу закинуть. И еще я скоро буду Asterisk настраивать на одном из серваков, но на него я уже скинул пароль.

Comment: _-для поиска того, что я предложил, это несущественно._ А как же Permission denied?

Comment: *А как же Permission denied?* — настройки и скрипты, используемые *xen*-ом, по идее, должны быть читабельны всем. файлы-то какие-нибудь нашлись?

Comment: Я сначала не там искал, подумал, что нужно искать на domu. На Dom0 у меня есть root права, и там ничего не нашлось. И кстати все команды xm выполняются только под рутом, _настройки и скрипты, используемые xen-ом, по идее, должны быть читабельны всем_, как они могут быть читабельны тогда, у меня с этой учеткой на виртуалке вообще почти никакую команду из /bin/ выполнить нельзя. Но есть один странный момент, я могу подцепится к корневому разделу этой виртуалки LiveCD, и сделать всё что угодно, удалить или закинуть что-нибудь, но пароль скинуть и установить не могу, где смысл?

Comment: следующее место для поиска — стартовые скрипты в самих *domu*. поищите и проанализируйте все упоминания слов *shadow* и *passwd* в них. начните с `grep -rE 'shadow|passwd' /etc/rc*` (если не используется systemd, конечно).

Comment: Всё что найдено: _/etc/rc.sysinit:    if [ -x /usr/bin/passwd ]; then 
/etc/rc.sysinit:        /usr/bin/passwd root_     _/etc/rc.d/init.d/saslauthd:MECH=shadow_. Причем это найдено во многих файлах, но похоже, что это не то.

Answer (score 1):

Извиняюсь, но считаю нужным уточнить - а у Вас случайно какой-нибудь SELinux не установлен? Текст ошибок не помню, но поведение в общем-то похожее.
(дада, по принципу Оккамы: *"верным решением обычно бывает самое простое"*)

В общем виде, для сброса пароля просто грузимся из GRUB'a с опцией single, и далее:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
# passwd
# touch /.autorelabel
# reboot
```

Поглядывайте ещё [вот сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448061/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-domu), обе проблемы явно из одного места растут.

Comment: дело в том, что я написал уже в первом посте что у меня это не сработало. Не подскажете как проверить стоит там SELinux или нет и как от него избавиться если  это возможно и если в этом действительно проблема. > При загрузке single mode требует пароль от root:

> Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

> При нажатии Control-D просто загружается как обычно и требует ввести имя пользователя и пароль.

Comment: Дело в том, что это моя темя у вас в ссылке.)))

Comment: Ну, если есть доступ к разделу, то глянуть здесь:
`/etc/selinux/config` или `/selinux/config`
и заменить строку `SELINUX=enforcing` на `SELINUX=disabled`

Comment: Да, доступ к разделу есть, с LVM я уже разобрался.

Comment: Дело в том, что в domu в etc нет папки selinux, есть папка selinux в корне, но в ней нет файла config. В Dom0 есть и в корне и в /etc папка selinux, в корне она вообще пустая, а в /etc есть файл config, но там всё отключено - SELINUX=disabled